# Deleted files with WinSCP

Tags: windows, scp, move

I selected some files and wanted to move them to another folder. All I did was this, using WinSCP:

Right click, *Move to*...

[image]

and all files were deleted. So the last folder had additional `*. *` in it. I accidentally deleted the slash between them. Any suggestions? Any Recycle Bin or something for this?

Comment: Using WinSCP isn't using the 'mv' command...

Comment: you think that WinSCP is using some other command when you are moving files?

Comment: Sounds like something you should ask the WinSCP devs... as you are essentially asking for support using a windows program.

Comment: I can't see what the image is supposed to show. It's not clear at all what you did or if the files were actually deleted or just move to an unexpected location. If you are having issues with a piece of Windows software, then I suggest you ask on the [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) site instead.

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried what you've described, and WinSCP reports an error:

```
General failure (server should provide error description).
Error code: 4
Error message from server: Failure
```

What I did was create a folder `thing`, then try to move a selection of two files to `thing*.*` (instead of WinSCP's offered `thing/*.*`). The first file was renamed to be my target directory name but with the file's original suffix. The remaining file stayed untouched. Looking at WinSCP debug, I would imagine that if you had two or more files each with a different suffix, they would all successfully be renamed to match the directory name with each keeping its original file suffix:

```
. 2021-03-22 15:47:49.200 Moving file "do2a.eml" to "/home/roaima/thing.eml".
> 2021-03-22 15:47:49.201 Type: SSH_FXP_RENAME, Size: 58, Number: 5394
…
. 2021-03-22 15:47:49.205 Moving file "do2b.eml" to "/home/roaima/thing.eml".
> 2021-03-22 15:47:49.205 Type: SSH_FXP_RENAME, Size: 58, Number: 5650
…
< 2021-03-22 15:47:49.207 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 5650
< 2021-03-22 15:47:49.207 Status code: 4, Message: 5650, Server: Failure, Language:
. 2021-03-22 15:47:49.208 Asking user:
. 2021-03-22 15:47:49.208 Error moving file 'do2b.eml' to '/home/roaima/thing.eml'. ("General failure (server should provide error description).
```

Results

```
test1.txt → thing.txt
test2.txt → [error]
```

and

```
test1.txt → thing.txt
test2.lst → thing.lst
other.exe → thing.exe
```

You should find your files, although the first of each selection with a common extension may have been renamed similarly to the original target directory name.